# create new svg line using existing lines

Tags: svg

I need to create center of the two perpendicular using x,y coordinates with same line length .This is my svg lines.

```
<svg width="140" height="140">

   <line x1="0"  y1="0" x2="0" y2="90" style="stroke:#006600;"/>
   <line x1="0"  y1="0" x2="90" y2="0" style="stroke:#006600;"/>
</svg>
```

Here i found out x,y coordinates using the formula.I used 45 degree to get the middle line coordinates.

```
// find middle line (x,y) using radius 90 
// formula x = 90 * sin(45) -> 77
// formula y = 90 * cos(45) -> 47
```

and the new line is

```
<line x1="0"  y1="0" x2="77" y2="47" style="stroke:#006600;"/>
```

But when drawn it doesn't look like the expected output. Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is more about some mathematical calculations instead of programming. Try asking a question in general (without in context of SVG) at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your degrees to radians, formula is `degrees * Math.PI / 180`, with this result you get:

```
<line x1="0"  y1="0" x2="62.51" y2="64.7" style="stroke:#006600;"/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b0xpo2nL/

Comment: Is this correct to find x value . `90 * Math.sin(45 * Math.PI / 180)`

Comment: Thanks for you help @Duopixel

Comment: Indeed, that's the right syntax to calculate the coordinates @htoniv